# Selenium python, click agree to youtube cookie

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, cookies, youtube

I am trying do you Youtube data scraping, but stuck at the first step... accepting the cookie.

I have tried searching the "I agree" text and click but seems another element is obscuring it.

```
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'I agree')]")
for btn in buttons:
    btn.click()
```

Tried accessing div, seems to do the action but does not really click

```
buttons = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="VfPpkd-dgl2Hf-ppHlrf-sM5MNb"]//button')
buttons.click
```

any pointer on how to click the button using python + selenium?
[button html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcBLg.png)

https://consent.youtube.com/m?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fresults%3Fsearch_query%3Dpost%2Bdriver&gl=FR&m=0&pc=yt&uxe=23983172&hl=en&src=1

Answer (score 2):

To click on `I agree` button to accept cookies on YouTube. The button is present inside an `iframe` and you need to switch the `iframe`. Use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for frame available and switch it.
[image]

---

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID,"iframe")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'I agree')]").click()
```

To jump out from frame you need to use

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Please import below libraries

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: It seems like we doesn't hit the same consent page.
This one seems to be structured differently. Maybe because european law thingy.

https://consent.youtube.com/m?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2F&gl=FR&m=0&pc=yt&uxe=23983172&hl=en&src=1

Answer (score 0):

This function is working for me..Most of the time it's showing in a form and sometimes you need to click on this particular button. Sometimes it's not showing at all.

```
bypass_consent(driver):
    try:
        consent = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.XPATH, "//input[@type='submit' and @value='I agree']")))
        consent.submit()
    except:
        try:
            consent = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
                'button.VfPpkd-LgbsSe.VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-k8QpJ.VfPpkd-LgbsSe-OWXEXe-dgl2Hf.nCP5yc.AjY5Oe.DuMIQc.IIdkle')
            consent.click()
        except:
            pass
```

You need to import the followings:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Answer (score 0):

As YouTube changes so frequently and behaves individually region to region there are a variety of different solutions. From your feedback I'd suggest along the lines of below

```
bypass_popup(driver):
    driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ")

    consent_button_xpath = "//button[@aria-label='Agree to the use of cookies and other data for the purposes described']"
    consent = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
        (By.XPATH, consent_button_xpath)))

    consent = driver.find_element_by_xpath(consent_button_xpath)
    consent.click()
```

What you want to do is wait for the pop-up to appear first, this is `WebDriverWait` & then as you are already to find it with `find_element_by_xpath` and then a simple `click()`

Due to the obfuscated nature of the web today the above takes advantage of accessibility properties which should mean it remains a tweak away whenever YouTube next changes their UI again, as accessibility should always be present.